# Who's responsible for deployment?

Tags: deployment, process, release-management

I work as an in-house developer for a manufacturing company.  We make software for the manufacturing process, not really control software, more like process flow.

We are using a Scrum process to develop the software, albeit tailored to fit with our team and environment, and this is working quite well.  We're coming to the end of a sprint and the software is at a stage where the product owner wants to deploy it.

Previously, i.e. before Scrum, we would have deployed the software.  Now I feel like we have developed the software, we've passed all the user-defined/agreed release tests and demonstrated the software to the PO with a simulator, **we have achieved our goals**.  We are ready to provide deployment support but I don't think it should be our responsibilty to deploy.

What are other peoples experiences?  Should the dev team do the deployment or should we just hand over the completed software to the PO and provide support?

**Summing up**

A lot of great responses, thanks.  The question may seem like I'm trying to squirm out of work or responsibility, maybe I am a little ;o)  What I'm more interested in is other peoples processes.  The problem we face here is that if the dev team deploy the software then we end up providing 24/7 support to production for the software.  No prob, except there are only two of us.  So, to allow us to get back to developing software rather than providing support all the time I thought it might be helpful to get the "IT" team involved in development process.  Hopefully this will get the 'buy-in' and then allow them to deploy and provide first level support.  We also have a plant in Mexico and its difficult for the dev team to go and deploy there, it makes more sense for the local support to do it, with guidance/advice from the developers.

Just to let you know, the IT engineers did deploy the software, with guidance/advice from dev.  Its gone quite well, the customer is happy - he's got increased value for his software, and isn't that what its all about?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about management questions, not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think Scrum as a methodology addresses deployment responsibility.  I've worked for large organizations with a deployment team completely independent of the development team.  I've also worked at small organizations where the development team handles deployment.  Ideally, the deployment team is separate from development, but it would almost never be the PO (which I assume means product owner).  The PO usually signs off, but is not usually the best choice for handling deployment.

Answer (score 4):

Who gets the call at 3am when the software isn't working or a system died? If it's the dev team then by all means expect to own the deployment (since you own production).

Best practice for organizations that can support is to provide the Operations group with deployment instructions and good wishes. Bottles of scotch help too.

If your production controls are lax, than tighten them up. A book like "Visible Ops" is a great guide to getting things under appropriate levels of control in the appropriate hands.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a dev mgr with responsibility over multiple products. I have my dev teams produce builds of deployment artifacts, such as .war files, that can be simply deployed to Tomcat web server using it's manager interface or web service API. The configuration for the app is all set and self-contained within the .war file. Hence it is straightforward for the person doing deployment to just take it and "drop it in", so to speak.

If we don't get this level of ease of deployment to where deployment can be completely decoupled from the development team, then I view that as a failure on the dev team's part to adequately do their job.

The person doing deployment proceeds to release a given product to numerous customer sites - that's not a productive activity for me to let developers be doing - they have products to design and create as that is their specialization expertise.

In our organization the deployment responsibility also overlaps with the first tier production support responsibility.

We practice some scrum methodology but I've never viewed this issue as tied to software development process methodology, per se.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of structure I'm keen to setup.  We're a relatively small company so some trade-offs will probably be necessary.  Thanks for the detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

I would think as an "In-house" developer it would be your responsiblity (unless there is a specialised deployment team) to deploy the new software whereas if you were from an external company then it would be upto them to deploy it themselves, unless specified in the contract.

Answer (score 1):

1. the software process is not completed until the working software is in the hands of the users that need it - otherwise it's just "shelfware"
2. if there is no one else to be responsible for deployment and configuration management, then you're it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the project and what "deployment" means for you.  Since I am a web developer, deploying mostly .NET applications with an Sql Server database, I always prefer the deployment be done by a release manager or deployment manager.  Why?  Because separation of jobs ensures that problems are caught when they need to be.

The developers job should be to provide the required objects or instructions on how to deploy, then someone else deploys to a staging environment.  If something goes wrong during deployment to staging, the deployment instructions are corrected until the deployment to staging works flawlessly.  That way, there will hopefully be no mistakes when the same deployment script is used to move the code to production.  In other words, not only must you test your code but also the deployment script.

of course, in the real world, this doesn't always happen because of personnel issues, but this would be my ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Seems fairly simple to me- if not you, then who?  Would actual deployment responsibility have fallen to some other team before you started using Scrum?  If not, then I don't see why Scrum would change that.

Answer (score 0):

If the dev team was providing the deployment before scrum, they should continue to do so, unless Management has specifically said that someone else should do it.  If managment hasn't said, then they haven't really thought about it, and just expected that it would happen magically, like it always has.

If you don't like that, bring it up with management, but do the work until told differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to man-up and deploy the software. unless you are working in an organization that has some kind of serious data security issues and or SOX issues with allowing the unclean to deal with the production end of things.

I agree with the first comment - SCRUM has nothing to do with it. In fact I would think it's far better for you to be deploying as you'll know first hand how well things are working and be right there to get feedback from those users.